# Positronium hyper-fine structure

Tags: atomic-physics

In positronium, the electron and positron can be anti-parallel which gives us a total spin = 0.
And for electron and positron parallel we have a total spin 1.

Is my reasoning correct if i say :

In the case of the hyper-fine structure splitting the  state with total spin 0 has lower energy then the one with total spin 1, because of the spin value.

Comment: Have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium?

Comment: i have but it doesn't say anything about the energy levels of different states (dependent from total Spin value).Since i have no idea what the formula for hyperfine structure energy is and how to adjust it for a positronium, i thought of explaining which one has lower energy by the reason i gave in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already know the answer and you are just trying to build an intuition for it. But in case you want numbers, in positronium the singlet does indeed have lower energy than the triplet ([source](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1138/1/012007/pdf)):
[image]

The reasoning is the same as in the more common example of ortho- and para- Helium (triplet and singlet respectively): the singlet has total spin $=0$ and its spin wavefunction is hence antisymmetric upon label exchange. The spatial wavefunction will therefore be symmetric, meaning it favours the bunching of the electron/positron pair. The pair will, on average, be closer to each other, hence experiencing a *larger* attractive interaction. Which increases the binding energy and hence pushes the singlet energy level farther down.

So your "because of the spin value" needs a bit of elaboration, because per se it doesn't mean much.